# Rails 4.1 Routes and URL helpers are formatting the urls to controller/action.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've had this problem a few times.

If I use a url helper like `follow_users_path(@user)` where I should be getting `users/follow/2` I am actually getting `users/follow.2`

I've managed to resolve it with fiddling a few times before, but I don't actually know what is causing this issue.

Has anyone else experiences this? I'm assuming there's something specific that i'm doing wrong and I'd like to know what it is.

Thanks

Comment: can you show also corresponding `route.rb`  file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you want `follow_user_path` (singular as a member route) which would give you `users/2/follow` assuming you've defined a member route

Comment: ahh of course, I had it in collection, which is why it was only giving me the plural. Thank you!